# Checked radiobutton doesn`t appear checked on the windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

A checked radiobutton doesn`t appear checked on the windows form.[image]

I have tested it with a messagebox and it written has checked...

You can ask for more code/information.
The language is french.

Thanks for help

New picture: The console output is correct according to my sql database.
[image]

```
// LOAD RADIOBUTTON
                SQLCommand.CommandText = ChargementRadiobuttonCommandText;
                reader = SQLCommand.ExecuteReader();

                // Rempli une liste avec les réponses provenant de la base de donné
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    ReponsesRadioButton.Add(reader["ReponseRadioButton"].ToString());
                }

                //foreach (string current in ReponsesRadioButton)
                //{
                //    MessageBox.Show(current);
                //}
                //MessageBox.Show("0: " + ReponsesRadioButton[0]);
                //MessageBox.Show("11 " + ReponsesRadioButton[11]);
                //MessageBox.Show("cathegorie: " + SessionQuestionGeneral.getintCathegorieActuel().ToString());

                //nombreDeQuestions = 0;

                //switch (SessionQuestionGeneral.getintCathegorieActuel())
                //{
                //    case 1:
                //        nombreDeQuestions = 12;
                //        break;

                //    case 2:
                //        nombreDeQuestions = 7;
                //        break;

                //    case 3:
                //        nombreDeQuestions = 7;
                //        break;

                //    case 4:
                //        nombreDeQuestions = 3;
                //        break;
                //}

                //for (int questionDeLaFenetre = 0; questionDeLaFenetre < nombreDeQuestions; questionDeLaFenetre++)
                //{ 

                foreach (string ReponseRadioButton in ReponsesRadioButton)
                { 
                //

                    switch (ReponseRadioButton)
                    {
                        case "En accord":
                            listRadioButtonEnAccord[iterationQuestion].Checked = true;

                            break;
                        case "En desaccord":
                            listRadioButtonEndesaccord[iterationQuestion].Checked = true;
                            break;

                        case "Non applicable":
                            listRadioButtonNonapplicable[iterationQuestion].Checked = true;
                            break;
                    }
                    //MessageBox.Show(iterationQuestion.ToString() + " " + ReponseRadioButton);
                    iterationQuestion++;

                }
                //MessageBox.Show("listRadioButtonEnAccord10 " + listRadioButtonEnAccord[10].Checked.ToString());
                //MessageBox.Show("listRadioButtonEndesaccord10 " + listRadioButtonEndesaccord[10].Checked.ToString());
                //MessageBox.Show("listRadioButtonNonapplicable10 " + listRadioButtonNonapplicable[10].Checked.ToString());

                //MessageBox.Show("listRadioButtonEnAccord11 " + listRadioButtonEnAccord[11].Checked.ToString());
                //MessageBox.Show("listRadioButtonEndesaccord11 " + listRadioButtonEndesaccord[11].Checked.ToString());
                //MessageBox.Show("listRadioButtonNonapplicable11 " + listRadioButtonNonapplicable[11].Checked.ToString());
                reader.Close();
                ReponsesRadioButton.Clear();
                iterationQuestion = 0;

                // LOAD LABEL cathegorie
                SQLCommand.CommandText = cathegorieCommandText;
                reader = SQLCommand.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    cathegorieText.Text = reader["nomCathegoriequestiongenerale"].ToString();
                }
                reader.Close();
```

Comment: _I have tested it with a messagebox_ an option, but usually the worst. Test with Console.WriteLine and of course the debugger. Both won't mess up the UI.. - We can't do that for you!

Comment: Good idea, My console wasnt enable so I switched to a console application. It's better to see results but the results are the same all radiobutton are well checked in the console but not in the form. Thanks for your help

Comment: you can use Console.Write(Line) in a Winfroms app just as well. The output go to the output pane in VS.

Comment: Oh, good that's handy. I needed to select Debug in the: Show output from:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem with this: `reponseGroupBox[iterationQuestion].Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()`
seem to be more effective.

```
foreach (string ReponseRadioButton in ReponsesRadioButton)
                {
                    foreach (RadioButton radioButtonActuel in reponseGroupBox[iterationQuestion].Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()) // Pour chaque RadioButton du reponseGroupBox associé à questionActuel
                    {
                            if (radioButtonActuel.Text == "En accord" && ReponseRadioButton == "En accord")
                            {
                                radioButtonActuel.Checked = true;
                            }

                            if (radioButtonActuel.Text == "En desaccord" && ReponseRadioButton == "En desaccord")
                            {
                                radioButtonActuel.Checked = true;
                            }

                            if (radioButtonActuel.Text == "Non applicable" && ReponseRadioButton == "Non applicable")
                            {
                                radioButtonActuel.Checked = true;
                            }
                    }
                    iterationQuestion++;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried the code below?

```
this.Update();
```

or

```
this.Refresh();
```

Do this to update your form, in some method in Form class.

Comment: I've tried them, but I've seen no effect. I've tried them at the end of my load function. It is the right place?

Comment: Where is the declaration of `listRadioButtonNonapplicable` and the where where the elements are added?

Comment: The list is declared private like this         private List<RadioButton> listRadioButtonNonapplicable; and I've added each radiobutton like that inside the constructor:             listRadioButtonNonapplicable = new List<RadioButton>();
            listRadioButtonNonapplicable.Add(Nonapplicable1);
            listRadioButtonNonapplicable.Add(Nonapplicable2);
...

Comment: I am sorry, but you made all things that I can imagine be able and useful to do.

Comment: Ok, I`ve just added a new picture. If it bring an idea.